# Parse data with C header files which defined the structures

Tags: c, parsing, debugging, data-structures

I have a C header file like this:

```
#define NAME_LEN 8
#define DEV_MAX  4

typedef struct __device
{
    int iDevID;
    int iDevSN;
}DEVICE;

typedef struct __person
{
    int iID;
    char acName[NAME_LEN];
    DEVICE aDevices[DEV_MAX];
}PERSON;
```

and a binary data file maybe like this:

```
0000000 01 00 08 00 4a 61 63 6b 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00
0000020 11 11 11 11 0b 00 00 00 22 22 22 22 0c 00 00 00
0000040 33 33 33 33 0d 00 00 00 44 44 44 44
```

All that what I need is to **visulized data representation with field names using the C header file** above.... 
It'll be better like this...

```
m--iID : 0x80001
m--acName : Jack
m--aDevices[]
|--aDevices[0]
|--|--iDevID : 0xa
|--|--iDevSN : 0x11111111
|--aDevices[1]
|--|--iDevID : 0xb
|--|--iDevSN : 0x22222222
|--aDevices[2]
|--|--iDevID : 0xc
|--|--iDevSN : 0x33333333
|--aDevices[3]
|--|--iDevID : 0xd
|--|--iDevSN : 0x44444444
```

or other structured data .. xml / python pickle / json strings / whatever

Of course, the header file which I faced is far more complicated, there will be a msgtype and a msglenth field in the data, so I can find out which is the correct structure and how long is it.

Comment: I think your best bet would be to write something in C that would include this header file and then read the data and cast it to your structure type before displaying it accordingly.

Comment: @Useless thanks for helping.. I need to put the data into the structures in header files, friendly shown , like Visual Studio, for debugging... I will use one of the fields in the struct to distinguish different struct types...

Comment: @AleksG YES, or just parse the headerfile, data will come from network or files, and I have the data structures, there will be a msgtype and a msglenth field in the data, so I can find out which is the correct structure and how long is it.

Comment: +1 for Aleks solution: be aware that the compiler won't respect the order of your structure attributes, offsets etc... You can't know how the data is ordered in the binary file.

Comment: @Jérôme thanks, the date itself will insure no offsets, and just consider I know how the data is ordered exactly ^_^

Comment: Actually, you can use the offsetof macro to get the offset of an attribute inside a struct. So you may need an important header for your binary file.

Comment: FYI, GDB can display almost exactly the information you list based on the DWARF debug info of a binary that uses the types. If you read the data to memory, set a `PERSON*` to that data and trigger a breakpoint, GDB will happily print the structure with the correct names and values (even without source)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson how can GDB know which struct to use based on one field of the structure?

Comment: Dwarf symbol is a good lead. However, you would need to create your binary with libdwarf, which could add a lot a stuff... The easier is maybe to compile a simple object containing a static structure, and play around with readelf, dwarfdump, objdump, pahole...

Comment: @Jérôme pahole fits me well, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

How badly do you need that?

A possible solution might be to make a GCC plugin or a [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) extension (MELT is a domain specific language to extend GCC), but to do that you'll need to understand in some details the internal representation of GCC (notably Tree, and perhaps Gimple), and that will take you some time (days, not hours).

If your declarations are simpler, perhaps consider using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) (or maybe the RPCXDR parser), but that supposes that you are able to change or simplify them.

Answer (score 0):

If the binary format were identical to the memory layout of your structure, you could just cast it, no parsing required (with some caveats). However, that evidently isn't what you mean, since your hex dump and sample output don't match that interpretation.

You'll need to actually explain your format though: as described below, it isn't obvious.

---

You seem to have fixed-length 4-octet integers in little-endian order, OK.

If I assume variable length strings with a nul-terminator, `4a 61 63 6b 00 = acName:"Jack"` and `0a 00 00 00 = iDevID:0x0a` looks ok, but there is a 3-octet sequence between them I don't know the meaning of.

Or is `Jack` not nul-terminated, in which case it's fixed at 4 characters long and not the 8 you defined for `NAME_LEN`? That would make `00 6f 70 65` another 4-byte integer, but I still don't know what it means.

...

Comment: it is `4a 61 63 6b 00 00 00 00` actually, sorry for my mistake

Comment: there are many different structures, data will come from network or files, there will be a msgtype and a msglenth field in the data, so I can find out which is the correct structure and how long is it.